# Does it exist an API for "International Settings" in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, extensibility

I'm working on Visual Studio Extensibility and I need to set the "shell" language from code. In other words, I'm looking for an API to do the same you can do "by hand" with the *Tools -> Options... -> Environment -> International Settings* property page.
Up to now I didn't find any reference: hints and suggestions are welcome. ;-)
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: to clarify a bit the question, I need to set the current language of Visual Studio itself (actually of an Isolated Visual Studio Shell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post here the current results of our (my coworker and me) search.
We found something at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165643.aspx .
In particular you can access *that* kind of options with
`DTE.Properties("Environment", "International")`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914356

Comment: I thank you, but the article is about setting culture inside a generic Windows application you write. Perhaps I was not clear enough in the question, but I need to set the current language of Visual Studio itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ask on win32 api newsgroup (it's a FAQ)

news://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32

Comment: Thank you. I went through the archive of the group but I wasn't able to find what I'm looking for. Can you give some more details?
See my (tentative) answer for something we find in the meanwhile.